# Find for which parameters the integral converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Find for which $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the integral
$$
\int_0^1 x^{a-b-1} \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^b} \right)dx
$$
converges.

---

I managed to show the integral converges for $a>b, a>0$ and for $b<0, a>b$. However, according to Mathematica the integral also converges for $a>0, b>a$. How can I show that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1x^{a-b-1}\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x^b}\right)~dx&=\int_\infty^1\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{a-b-1}\cos x^b~d\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\\&=\int_1^\infty x^{-a+b-1}\cos x^b~dx\\&=\int_1^\infty\left(x^\frac{1}{b}\right)^{-a+b-1}\cos x~d\left(x^\frac{1}{b}\right)\\&=\dfrac{1}{b}\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{a}{b}}\cos x~dx\end{align}$$

$\therefore$ The integral converges when $0<\dfrac{a}{b}<1$ , i.e. $\begin{cases}a>0~\text{and}~a<b\\a<0~\text{and}~a>b\end{cases}$